# Is there a good (free) way to see site and/or search traffic?

Tags: data-request, internet

Several years back, if memory serves, I was able to access on Google, the site traffic or search traffic for a wide number of large corporations. This was through a portal (I think Google Analytics, but it might've been a different portal). I went back to Google Analytics (GA), and it appears that the only data one can access through GA is for one's own site (or a site to which one has been granted access). I also did a web search, and saw that there are various organizations offering to sell estimated site traffic or search traffic data.

Is there any way (hopefully for free), through Google or other browsers/aggregators to see, for instance, total web traffic for a specific company's (let's call it "International MegaCorp") websites, or total searches for "International MegaCorp" on a big platform such as Google (or across platforms)?

Comment: I'd be surprised if you could actually ever see other site's GA traffic. There are some open web logs, though, mostly for government orgs and portal.

Comment: similar question https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/13118/1511